# Include peerjs client library in node application

Tags: node.js, npm, p2p

I have installed PeerJs Client library (https://npmjs.org/package/peerjs) using "npm install peerjs".
The Read me section explains its usage in browser based client. However I want to use this library in node.js application using "include".
How would I be able to include this library in my node.js application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no current way to do this, but progress is allegedly under way. See this issue: http://github.com/peers/peerjs/issues/103